# Ngnix - fpm php status page error

Tags: php, nginx, php7, php-fpm

I am trying to see the fpm status page through ngnix (http://example.com/status). I am getting "Access denied." While my web application is running without any issues. Thanks in advance for your time.

I am using

```
Linux : Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Ngnix : nginx/1.14.0
PHP : 7.0
```

Nginx conf

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php home.html

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main buffer=16k;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

    location ~ \.php$ {

            try_files $uri =404;

            # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
            fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            # fastcgi_index index.php;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }


    location = /status {
        access_log off;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        # allow 127.0.0.1;
        # deny all;
    }

    location ~  ^/mywebapp/(module1|module2){

            rewrite ^(/mywebapp/\w+)/(.*)$ $1/index.php?_url=/$2;

    }

}
```

No change in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
grep "pm.status_path" /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
pm.status_path = /status
```

Comment: Check `/var/log/nginx/error.log` to see the exact error message as to what was 'denied'.  Also note that you might need to clear your cache, as browsers are NOTORIOUS at caching "Access Denied" errors.  Also, your 'Deny' needs to come before your 'Allow' rule as well, in order to permit yourself access AFTER denying all others access.

Comment: [error] 5078#5078: *51947 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/status' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: example.com, request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"

Comment: That suggests a PHP misconfiguration.  Check your PHP settings for `security.limit_extensions`.